# Putting a PHP variable as a text box value

Tags: php, variables, textbox

I am trying to write code that passes a php variable as a textboxes value.
Here is the following code I tried:

```
echo "<td>"."<input type='text' value='<?php echo $start_date; ?>'/>"."</td>"
```

This brings up an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

I have tried various methods of re-wording:

```
 echo "<input type='text' value='<?php echo $start_date?>'/>";
```

(this was purely to test as I would like the result in a table row)

but this shows:

```
<?php echo ?>
```

in the textbox and I also get this error: Notice: Undefined variable: start_date...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't need to* start one `echo` within another. The variable `$start_date` can be within double quotes and hence interpolated.

```
echo "<td><input type='text' value='$start_date'/></td>"; //no unnecessary concatentation
```

**EDIT:**

In case of *an associative array*, for example, to echo `$row['start_date']`

```
echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['start_date']."/></td>";
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed that.  Sadly I think the problem is with the variable as I get.... Notice: Undefined variable: start_date...this error? As with all of the answers, I get the same error.

Comment: @user1830632 That implies your variable `$start_date` isn't defined yet. Are you sure you are spelling it right?

Comment: yes all the variables are defined and work in this method: 
 echo "<td>".$row['end_date']."</td>"; perhaps I should incorporate the row?

Comment: Ahh, it is an element of the row associative-array then. You will have to do that. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have specified that! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
echo "<td>"."<input type='text' value='$start_date;'/>"."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to echo once, for example:

```
echo "<td>"."<input type='text' value='$start_date'/>"."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo '<td><input type="text" value="'.$start_date.'"/></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always took thin in your mind that if you enclose a variable inside "" double quotes than it can be echoed directly. You don't need use concatenation for this only. Eg

```
echo "<td>$rohit</td>"; //here you dont have to echo this like "<td>".$rohit."</td>".
```

In this as @Cthulhu said use it like that.