# How to have a php variable as a value to text box?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter framework. I need to assign a php variable from my controller page to the view page.
Here is my view page code.

```
<?php 
        foreach($service as $row)
              {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['employee']."/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['time']."/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['id']."/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['service']."/></td>";
                echo '</tr>';
              }
        ?>
```

This does not work for me? Can some one help me, I did this refering to this post [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357125/putting-a-php-variable-as-a-text-box-value%22%20check%20here%22)
But that answer is not working for me. When I have this in my page then my page display a blank view. Please help me solve this.Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
This is my controller function

```
 public function update()
     {
         $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
         $data['service'] = $this->billing_model->get_bill_by_id($id);
         $data['num_rows'] = count($data['service']);
         $data['main_content'] = 'admin/billing/edit';

         $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
     }
```

Here I get the id and call a model function>
This is my model function

```
public function get_bill_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('bill.employee');
        $this->db->select('bill.start_time');
        $this->db->select('bill.pid');
        $this->db->select('bill.description');
        $this->db->select('bill.type');

        $this->db->select('bill.price');
        $this->db->from('bill');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $users = array();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $users = $query->result_array();
        }

        return $users;   
    }
```

Comment: post your controller and model code

Comment: In what manner does it not work? Error or unexpected result? Explain that did you expect and the actual result.

Comment: How are we going to help you if you are not providing us sufficient information about your problem?

Comment: I have edited my post please refer it @Gautam

Comment: After having this code my page becomes blank. I have described it in my question. @MrMush

Comment: what is the variable you need from your controller to view?

Comment: What else I need to provide you for a answer ? @HardSpocker What is insufficient in my post can you please kindly describe it?

Comment: I already passed a variable service it is an array that has multiple values. @HardSpocker

Comment: you actually missed the single qoute

Comment: Yes I could find it now. Thanks for your support. @HardSpocker

Comment: take a break bro, drink some coffee. :) yw

Comment: Not bro :P sis @HardSpocker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91607/discussion-between-hard-spocker-and-anu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a single quote

```
value='".$row['employee']."->HERE<-
```

I prefer to use [heredoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for this, so I don't have to concern about quotes, i.e.

```
foreach($service as $row)
{               
echo <<< EOF
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='{$row['employee']}'/></td>
<td><input type='text' value='{$row['time']}'/></td>
<td><input type='text' value='{$row['id']}'/></td>
<td><input type='text' value='{$row['service']}'/></td>
</tr>
EOF;

}
```

---

**TIP:**

While developing, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, with this, you'll be able to see the errors and not just a "**blank page**"

Comment: Its little silly somehow now with your answer I learnt to debug my program. That a great answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anu You're very welcome :) If my answer helped you, please consider vote 1+ and accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !